# X-Ray Mode is Not Working

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, armature, bones

I'm new to Blender and still learning how to make a simple character, but when I started creating the Armature the X-Ray Mode is not working probably. I enabled it and I can't see the bones. That makes it hard to create the character skeleton.

here are screenshots of whats happening:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated ...

Comment: Please provide a bit more information. What settings have you tried? X-ray mode is working, I assure you that. :-)

Comment: @Gunslinger I Added a bone , moved it inside my mesh and then activated x-ray mode and it didn't show me anything, i Uploaded a screenshot to see whats exactly happening :)

Comment: @SoulsReaper Can you share the file, you may have changed something elsewhere. Use http://pasteall.org/blend

Comment: @iKlsR http://pasteall.org/blend/26374  

hope u can help :)

Comment: Somehow X-ray is getting enabled on your parent mesh whenever you enable it on your armature, however I have no idea why this is happeneing..

Comment: @gandalf3 do u recommend remake the character ?

i had a problem with scaling the head before and when i made a new file it worked ! 

i don't know whats wrong :/

Comment: @gandalf3, the object is pinned in the .blend file, so you can't select the armature's settings.

Comment: @CharlesL What do you mean it's pinned in the .blend file ?

please explain I'm new to blender

Comment: In the upper left hand corner of the object properties (the cube icon), there's an option to pin the settings. This will lock the panel and prevent you from changing the settings of any other object. Deselect the pin and you'll be able to change the settings for other objects. Screenshot of the pin option: http://i.imgur.com/dR0jjBJ.png

Comment: @CharlesL Thank you very much it works Now ! :D

Comment: @ideasman42 I disagree with closing this question. It is not phrased as a bug report, and as discovered by CharlesL this is not actually a bug.

Comment: @CharlesL Wow, I never knew you could do that, thanks! (it's
 really useful too..)

Comment: This is a misunderstanding about a draw mode, closing as non-constructive.

Comment: Post reopened. @CharlesL Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is you pinned the mesh settings in the properties panel, so you can change the settings of any other objects. Simply de-pin it so you can change the settings of the other objects:

[image]

Then, give the armature the X-Ray, because the object that has the X-Ray box checked is the one that will show through any other object. In this case, you want to to uncheck X-Ray on the mesh and check it for the armature.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as though you have x- ray set to the mesh; its the armature that should have x-ray checked not your mesh.

Comment: man I already tried that and it's not working , I already uploaded my file if u want to check it out :)

Comment: @SoulsReaper looked at the .blend. This is actually your issue. The mesh is being X-Rayed instead of the armature. When you check "X-Ray" your making that object show through any other object.

Comment: Steve's answer was the problem. My mesh had X-Ray enabled thus conflicting with the Bones's X-Ray. Make sure your mesh isn't "doubling-up" on the X-Ray mode.

Answer (score 1):

Because the x-[image]ray should bone it is not the object