# Objects showing through other objects in the BGE?

Tags: python, rendering, game-engine

I am having trouble with a rig I imported from MakeHuman. When I run the *Embedded Player* or the Standalone Player my character's facial features come through the mesh.

They are positioned properly, but for some reason they seem to get priority over the outer mesh and are displayed through the outer skin.

Here is a picture to illustrate my conundrum:

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload your blend file so we can check to see what is causing this?

Comment: My blend file was too big to upload but here is a link to my Q with the code and some extra info:   [link](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?332330-Imported-MakeHuman-modles-features-distort) Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to upload a file of almost unlimited size, you can use Google Drive (https://drive.google.com/) -- they give you 15GB of storage and the links don't ever expire.

Comment: However I can't help you with anything related to code because I'm not a programmer. But, if you want more help here on StackExchange, you should revise your question to explicitly describe the code you used and also add coding-related tags to your question so that the coding experts might be more inclined to examine the question. There are lots of coders here that might be able to help.

Comment: One thought I have, though, is that it might be that you have the teeth and eyes on a layer that is rendered on top of the body, in which case you would need to make sure the render layer containing the teeth and eyes is below the layer containing the body. I don't know if that's you issue, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Thanks Thom. On further testing the problem seems to be inconsistent, sometimes the character renders correctly in the Player but other times it distorts as per above image. This is without changing the code, fps or logic tic rate. I think it could either be a glitch of some kind with rendering, perhaps related to my pc graphics handler. The MakeHuman import does not use layers for the eyes, teeth and tongue (just layers for different bones). I guess the best I can do his prevent the logic from taking longer than the logic tic rate and hope the rest runs smoothly when I make the game a .exe

Comment: I think you have XRay on the teeth and the eyes. If you do, they'll show through any objects in front.

Comment: possible duplicate of [X-Ray Mode is Not Working](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6386/x-ray-mode-is-not-working)

Comment: Can you check to make sure that the body mesh doesn't have alpha transparency enabled for some reason? Sometimes, objects with Alpha enabled gets drawn in a weird order because of the lack of z-sorting.

Comment: X-ray does not work in the game engine, so I doubt this is the same issue as the X-ray mode problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way (and only one known to me) is to go to "user prefernces-editing" and in "Duplicate data" uncheck the "Metaball". Then duplicate problematic meshes. Duplicates shoudn't have these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Game Mode:  In Properties tab, go to the material section and open the game setting.  Set the mode to alpha clip, alpha blend.  The problem is the order AI decide to prioritizes the order.